# OOP design pattern for program refactoring

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, refactoring

my problem is refactoring a program according to object-oriented programming principles. Program is running in a while loop endlessly and all operations in this main while loop. This main cycle has a switch-case statement.
It has 11 cases and all cases are represent statements like `unplanned_stop`, `planned_stop`, `read_data_from_x`, `read_data_from_y`... Also, these states have if-else clauses in it to call different functions. Every state points to another state to the next step according to if-else decisions.

I  have searched and State Design Pattern is seemed good for this solution but I am not sure.
The main loop is like this:

```
while(programIsRunnning)
{
   switch(programState)
   {
      case state.StartOfLoop:
          if(..) doSomething();
          else doAnotherThing();
          programState = state.PlannedStop;
          break;
      case state.PlannedStop:
          if(..) programState = state.ReadDataFromX;
          else programState = state.ReadDataFromY;
      case state.ReadDataFromX:
          if(..) programState = state.UnplannedStop;
          else programState = state.StartOfLoop;
      .
      .
      .
```

I hope I could explain enough. This design is nasty and hard to understand to where to implement new specifications. For every new request for the program, I have to edit other states and if-else clauses. I am a junior and all can I think is recoding it with OOP design patterns. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Hi, refactoring that into OOP sounds exactly what you should do :). Go right ahead! 
Stackoverflow works best for specific questions, for specific problems with reproducible code given.
When you have one of those, come back and make a new post :)

Comment: Well, what you have here _is_ a state machine. If you want (or need) to refactor it, you need to understand why it has been designed as a state machine, first. Is there some hardware involved? - Or do you just want "a OOP-style state machine" ?

Comment: And also: Do you have enough control over the code to make such a "major overhaul"? You'll need time, probably a lot of it and you'll need to _prove_ that you didn't break anything.

Comment: You can take a look at [stateless](https://github.com/dotnet-state-machine/stateless) for some insipration.

Comment: Yes it getting data from raspberry pi

Comment: OK, so I guess you want to keep the state machine, just _code_ it more OOPy, right? Then I'd second Guru's suggestion to get the help of some lib that abstracts a lot of the implementation detail of a state machine away, so you can focus on what the program needs to do, rather than how.

Comment: Why is your program built as a state machine in the first place?  It's always going to get hard to maintain as the number of states proliferates.  Try to let each state do more work so you can have fewer of them, and then the State pattern becomes reasonable.  Also note that in C#, you can use coroutines to get rid of state machines in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

Your task fits well in using the [State pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern), below I presented an example code of how the class dependency might look. We split the big switch into several classes, each of which is responsible for processing one state and can transfer the program to other states.

For example, I used the Python language, since it is quite visual, and sketched out several classes similar to the problem I once solved, I also explicitly added methods that are called for states when switching to it and leaving it, sometimes this is useful.

```
class StateInterface:
    def on_enter(self):
        ...

    def work(self):
        ...

    def on_leave(self):
        ...


class StateOne(StateInterface):
    def __init__(self, main_program):
        self.main_program = main_program

    def on_enter(self):
        # do some init
        ...

    def work(self):
        # do some work
        new_state = StateTwo(self.main_program)
        self.main_program.change_state(new_state)

    def on_leave(self):
        # do some clear
        ...


class StateTwo(StateInterface):
    ...


class MainProgram:
    def __init__(self, initial_state: StateInterface):
        self.current_state = initial_state

    def infinite_loop(self):
        while not self.stopped:
            self.current_state.work()

    def change_state(self, new_state: StateInterface):
        self.current_state.on_leave()
        self.current_state = new_state
        self.current_state.on_enter()
```